# Is it possible for doxygen to extract static functions only in a certain module?

Tags: c, doxygen

In my `main.c` there are many functions marked with `static`, but that would be nice to have documented for the next guy (or myself) since they are application critical/specific. However, extracting *all* static members is extreme, since most modules use the `static` keyword for functions specifically to hide these details. The only reason that `static` is being used in the `main.c` file is on the off chance that it is somehow included as a dependency into some other project, although it really isn't intended for such a purpose (it's an embedded application). This doesn't seem like such a radical use case and I frequently see heavy use of `static` functions in `main.c` even though it will likely never be included elsewhere.

Using `doxygen`, is there a way to extract static functions only in one module?

Comment: *static* means no global. Is used to reduce a number of global symbols in the scope and make those functions inaccessible from other objects. It allows using same static names in different files. So, i do not understand your explanation. But in any case, you can wrap unneeded function within a macro non-definied in doxygen or make them *internal* for doxygen. You can filter out files using patterns in doxygen.  I do not believe that there is anything specific about static functions for selected files.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is set `EXTRACT_STATIC = YES` (surprisingly) and also set `EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES = NO` in your doxyfile. Then, do not include a `\file` command at the top of any C file, except for the one C file that contains `main()`. But do include `\file` at the top of every H file that declares the global functions in your other C files.

You will find that any doxygen markup of those global functions will be included in the doxygen output, even if that mark-up is in the C files that no longer include a `\file` command. And, with luck, you will have your desired static functions in your main module documented too.

Comment: For reference with which doxygen version did you test this?

Comment: This is the kind of idea I was hoping for. I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: @albert it was 1.8.17